# Showing JSON file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hy everyone. I've been trying to import my JSON to HTML and make it into a table. My JSON contains:

```
{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
},
```

and my html is (i got this way from my friend but i dont think this works on my case):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"> </script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $.get('anime.json', function(obj){
            var str = "";
            str+="<table border = '1'><tr><th>No</th><th>Judul</th></tr>";

            $.each(obj, function(n,data){
                str+="<tr><td>"+(n+1)+"</td>";
                str+= "<td>"+data.cover_title+"</td></tr>";
            });
            $('#media').html(str);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id = "media"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also try another ways from youtube, but it's still not working. What can I do? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function tries to automatically parse the json string and convert it to an array but when it encounters an internal error the success callback won't run.
Your json format doesn't look valid, you can confirm using this

```
$.get('a.json', function(obj){
    var str = "";
    str+="<table border = '1'><tr><th>No</th><th>Judul</th></tr>";

    $.each(obj, function(n,data){
        str+="<tr><td>"+(n+1)+"</td>";
        str+= "<td>"+data.cover_title+"</td></tr>";
    });
    $('#media').html(str);
})
.catch( function(e){
    alert('Error');
});
```

Your should correct it like

```
[{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
}]
```